# How to show a div with initial width equal min-width in IE but can expand as necessary?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to have a div to have an initial width equal to a min-width say 800px and expand in width as elements inside grow in width. I did a `<div style="min-width: 800px".. />` but in IE the div starts with a width less than 800px, sum of widths of inner elements.

How can this be done for IE? I can't use width:800px because elements inside can't expand beyond 800px.
I use jQuery.

**Addition:**

I am using IE8. I just created a new page with an outer div with just min-width and inner div with a width. The outer width used the whole screen width. Not same issue but related. I will have to find out why my page behaves differently.

Comment: Please specify which IE version(s) you are targeting.

Comment: Please share more of your code.  `min-width` works in IE as of IE7.  A jsFiddle repro would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [CSS expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
div {    
    display: inline-block;
    width: inherit;  

    /* min-width for good browsers */
    min-width: 800px; 

    /* CSS expression for older IE */
    width: expression(document.body.clientWidth < 800? "800px": "auto");    
}
```

Example here: [min-width CSS expression hack](http://jsfiddle.net/vnX6t/5/). The yellow background is the outer div
the dotted line is the inner element so the div keeps size properties of it's child :)

Comment: if I make the inner div width 600, the outer is 600. It should be 800.

Comment: I've added your code from jsfiddle.  That way when people hit the page they'll see what you're doing right away, even if jsfiddle is down.

Comment: Adding inline-block to the outer div did the trick. There's no need for the expression and inherit.

Answer (score 0):

In IE6 *min-width*, *max-width*, *min-height* and *max-height* properties does not work. You can create a conditional stylesheet and use *width* for IE6 and *min-width* for the other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can target IE6 by using underscore hack. Example:

```
<div style="min-width:800px;_width:800px;">...</div>
```

For max-width/height, you have to use IE-proprietary expression() property: http://www.svendtofte.com/code/max_width_in_ie/